# Do you call the feeling of acid burns as 燃える too?

Tags: usage, verbs, word-usage

Doesn't have to be the kind that melts your face off. Like your detergent(alkali but nvm that) prickling your hand after leaving it for a bit too long on your hand.

Would toothpaste or menthol's effect on your skin be called 燃える too?

Basically want to know if moeru can be applied to non-fire related words too and what words would be used for these situations. I get the feeling it's some onomatopoeic word though if possible I'm looking for an actual word too.

Comment: ピリピリ (also ヒリヒリ) come to mind... but that's not an answer if you're more interested in 燃える than in "feeling of acid burns" and are excluding onomatopoeic words.

Comment: The word that is perhaps more commonly put to use when describing a burning sensation is another word for "burn", 焼ける (or the transitive counterpart 焼く). It's associated with a fiercer kind of pain than prickling, though.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @Earthling, I think 「ヒリヒリ（する）」 works perfectly for these situations. If you're looking for an actual word (or verb) for it, how about 「しみる」?

> **しみる** (沁みる)
>   ２ 液体や気体などの刺激を受けて痛みを感じる。しむ。「消毒薬が傷口にしみる」「歯にしみる」
>   ([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/100876/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%97%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B/))

Edit: 「チクチク（する）」 might be more suitable for "detergent prickling your hand". 「チクチク」 is often used to describe an itch, a prickling or tingling pain.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you also describe the feeling of "detergent prickling your hand after leaving it for a bit too long on your hand" with ヒリヒリ?

Comment: @Earthliŋ そうですね、「ヒリヒリ」って、「（皮膚の表面が）痛い」って感じですので、prickling には「チクチク」のほうがいい気がしますね・・（洗剤（洗濯用？）を長く手に付けておくとどうなるかちょっとわかんないんですけど・・）